# prevent @imports and hex codes in specific files with scss lint

Tags: sass, lint

I'm in the process of configuring scss lint and want to prevent using @import in partials that aren't on a white list. The idea being that @imports are only allowed in a manifest file. Is this possible?

I'd also like to do a similar thing with hex codes so they're limited to only being defined in a single file. I know I can prevent them being defined raw in the file but this doesn't stop people form defining color variables anywhere they like. I'd like to limit them to one file.

Thank you